# Issue with wsdl / soap

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, pfx

I'm using a C# WebApi. I have added a Service Reference to a WebService.
The WebService requires a Certificate to be present, which I have included in my project.

Now the problem is that everything is working as it should when I run it on my local machine. However, when I deploy it to live, it won't work. Once I run it on live, the application can't find the .pfx file, which is definitely included in the project and in the right location (Project root).

I've tried HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath, however neither of these seem to work, since it still says it can't find the file specified.

I just don't understand how it can work flawless on my local machine, but then it doesn't work on live.

Can anyone help me? It's driving me nuts.

Update:
Okay I have found that the PFX file is not the issue. I checked if it could find the file with 'File.Exists' and it can in fact find the file. I've found that the error occurs when I try to create a new X509Certificate from the given path

X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(pfxPath, pfxPassword);

where the pfxPath would be the path to the file which I just confirmed does exist.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've figured it out. It seems I had to set the 'Load User Profile' option to 'true' in the Application Pool advanced settings for my website.

It's working as intended now!